# How can I make my navbar completely responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ios

I recently made an Apple navbar, but I have some trouble with getting it to be responsive. https://codepen.io/51LV3R/pen/OJRxNdj is link for the navbar. The searchbar which is supposed to be in the center transforms after I close it on a mobile device. Does anyone know how can I fix that? As you can see at the bottom of the HTML code, I tried using jQuery. Also, can I add HTML elements through DOM wherever I want? Because I want on click to searchbar to show the button 'cancel' much like the Apple one does. Thanks for help. https://www.apple.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cubing Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul class="nav-list nav-list-mobile">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <div class="mobile-menu">
                            <span class="line line-top"></span>
                            <span class="line line-bottom"></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-apple" onmouseover="hover();"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-bag" onmouseover="hover();"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- nav list nav mobile -->
                <ul class="nav-list nav-list-larger">
                    <li class="nav-item nav-item-hidden">
                        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link nav-link-apple n1" onmouseover="hover();"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link n2" onmouseover="hover();">Mac</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=" nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link n3" onmouseover="hover();">iPad</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link n4" onmouseover="hover();">iPhone</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link n5" onmouseover="hover();">Watch</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" >
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link n6" onmouseover="hover();">TV</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link n7" onmouseover="hover();">Music</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link n8" onmouseover="hover();">Support</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" id="search" onclick="navbar();" class="nav-link nav-link-search n9" onmouseover="hover();"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item v2">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-bag n10" onmouseover="hover();"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="searchbox" id="searchbox">
                        <form>
                        <button class="confirm" disabled></button>
                        <input  type="text" class="search" id="box" placeholder="Search here" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
                        <span class="close-btn" onclick="navbarRemove();">
                            <span class="close-btn-left"></span>
                            <span class="close-btn-right"></span>
                        </span>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- nav list nav mobile -->
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($('html').width() <= 767) {
        $('#search').click(function(){
            $('.nav-link').addClass('hide-item')
            $('.searchbox').addClass('active')
            $('.nav-link').removeClass('activev2')
        })
        $('.close-btn').click(function(){
            $('.nav-link').removeClass('hide-item')
            $('.searchbox').removeClass('active')
            $('.nav-link').addClass('activev2')
        })
    }else{
        
    }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*,
*::before,
*::after{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'SF Pro Display', sans-serif;
}

a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container{
    max-width: 98rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2.2rem;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1400;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.4rem;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    backdrop-filter: blur(2rem);
}

.nav-list{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 -0.5rem;
}

.nav-list-mobile{
    display: none;
}

.nav-link{
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #e4e1e1;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

.nav-link:hover{
    opacity: .7;
    transition: .3s!important;
}

.nav-link.hide-item{
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: .5s;
}

.nav-link.activev2{
    transition: .5s;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.nav-link.activev2:hover{
    transition: .3s!important;
}

.n1.activev2{
    transition-delay: 0.0005s!important;
}

.n2.activev2{
    transition-delay: 0.0025s!important;
}

.n3.activev2{
    transition-delay: 0.005s!important;
}

.n4.activev2{
    transition-delay: 0.025!important;
}

.n5.activev2{
    transition-delay: 0.05s!important;
}

.n6.activev2{
    transition-delay: 0.1s!important;
}

.n7.activev2{
    transition-delay: 0.15s!important;
}

.n8.activev2{
    transition-delay: 0.2s!important;
}

.n9.activev2{
    transition-delay: 0.25s!important;
}

.n10.activev2{
    transition-delay: 0.3s!important;
}

.n10{
    transition-delay: 0.0005s!important;
}

.n9{
    transition-delay: 0.0025s!important;
}

.n8{
    transition-delay: 0.005s!important;
}

.n7{
    transition-delay: 0.025!important;
}

.n6{
    transition-delay: 0.05s!important;
}

.n5{
    transition-delay: 0.1s!important;
}

.n4{
    transition-delay: 0.15s!important;
}

.n3{
    transition-delay: 0.2s!important;
}

.n2{
    transition-delay: 0.25s!important;
}

.n1{
    transition-delay: 0.3s!important;
}

.nav-link-apple{
    width: 1.6rem;
    height: 3.5rem;
    background: url("img/apple.svg") center no-repeat;
}

.nav-link-search{
    width: 1.6rem;
    height: 4.4rem;
    background: url("img/search.svg") center no-repeat;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #e4e1e1;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    transition: opacity .5s;
    }
    
    .nav-link-search:hover{
        opacity: .7;
    }

.nav-link-bag{
    width: 1.4rem;
    height: 4.4rem;
    background: url("img/bag.svg") center no-repeat;
}

.searchbox{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-47%, -45%);
    width: 600px;
    height: 44px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .6s;
}

.searchbox.active{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay: .6s;
    transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
}

.searchbox input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.searchbox input:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

.close-btn{
    opacity: .7;
    transition: .5s;
}

.close-btn-left{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 1.7rem;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #979696;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.close-btn-right{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
     width: 1.7rem;
     height: 1px;
     background-color: #979696;
     cursor: pointer;
}

.close-btn:hover{
    opacity: 1.6;
}

.confirm{
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: url("img/idkv2.svg") center no-repeat;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    fill: #e4e1e1;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transform: translate(-160%, 180%);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    header{
        height: 4.8rem;
        transition: background .36s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.08, 0.24, 1),
                               height .56s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.08, 0.24, 1);
    }

    header .container{
        padding: 0;
    }

    .nav-list{
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .nav-list-mobile{
        display: flex;
    }

    .nav-item{
        width: 4.8rem;
        height: 4.8rem;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .nav-item-hidden{
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile-menu{
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1500;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .v2{
        display: none;
    }

    .line{
        position: absolute;
        width: 1.7rem;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #fff;
        transition: margin-top .3192s cubic-bezier(0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.96);
    }

    .line-top{
        margin-top: 4px;
    }

    .line-bottom{
        margin-top: -.8rem;
    }

    .active .line-top{
        margin-top: 0;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        transition: transform .3192s .1s cubic-bezier(0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.96);
    }

    .active .line-bottom{
        margin-top: 0;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transition: transform .3192s .1s cubic-bezier(0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.96);
    }

    header.active{
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .nav-link-apple{
        width: 1.8rem;
        height: 4.8rem;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1500;
    }

    .nav-link-bag{
        width: 1.6rem;
        height: 4.8rem;
        transition: opacity 1.5s;
    }

    .nav{
        position: relative;
    }

    .nav-link{
        font-size: 1.7rem;
        padding: 0;
        margin: auto 0;
    }

    .nav-list-larger{
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          display: block;
          padding: 10.5rem 5rem;
          z-index: 1000;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          opacity: 0;
          visibility: hidden;
          transition: opacity .3s;
    }

    .active .nav-list-larger{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .active .nav-link-bag{
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .3s;
    }

    .nav-list-larger .nav-item{
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    }

    .nav-list-larger .nav-item:nth-child(9){
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    .active .nav-list-larger .nav-item{
        animation: fadeIn .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .close-btn{
        display: none;
    }

    .n9{
        display: none;
    }

    .searchbox{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top: 8rem;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        background: #1D1D1F;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        width: 400px;
        transition: none;
    }

    .searchbox-active{
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: none;
        transform: translate(0)!important;
        transition: none;
    }

    @keyframes fadeIn {
        from{
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to{
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}

 @keyframes appear {
     from{
         transform: scale(0);
     }
     to{
         transform: scale(1);
     }
 }
```

```
const selectElement = (element) => document.querySelector(element);

selectElement('.mobile-menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectElement('header').classList.toggle('active');
});

function navbar(){
    document.querySelector('html').style.transition = ".2s"
    document.querySelector('html').style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
    setTimeout(()=> {
        document.querySelector('#box').focus()
    }, 1000)
}

function navbarRemove(){
    document.querySelector('html').style.transition = "0"
    document.querySelector('html').style.background = "none"
    document.getElementById("nav-link").style.transform = "scale(1)";
}
```

Comment: What does transform mean?

Comment: FSDford Like, when I open the mobile menu, it basically moves from the one spot to the center, and when I close the menu, it moves from the center back to that spot where it shouldn't be.

Comment: Do you mean the left side of the screen?

Comment: Where is the hover() function defined?  I would start by removing that.

Comment: Perhaps this happens because of the transition options. Searchbox appears immediately and the menu has a transition of x milliseconds that's why you see the search box ahead of the menu.

Comment: Vlad K. How can I fix that?

Comment: jqueryHtmlCSS Yeah, left side of the screen, when you open it on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said the problem was in transitions.
Remove the transition option of .6s from .searchbox in general css and add 1s transition in media queries where max-width: 767px. See the codepen:  https://codepen.io/codeweapon/pen/oNzGLZB

```css
.searchbox{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-47%, -45%);
    width: 600px;
    height: 44px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
/*     transition: .6s; */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
.searchbox{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top: 8rem;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        background: #1D1D1F;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        width: 400px;
        transition: 1s; /*add transition of 1s */
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work at all man.I still se the menu bar moving to the position where it should not be.

Comment: @VukStamenkovic Which browser do you use? I thought that you say that when you shrink down the browser window the search bar is flickering. You mean if you open up the menu the search bar moves from top to bottom?

Comment: Yeah, but the 'position: fixed;' seem to be the fix. No pun intended. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @VukStamenkovic No problem.